# How to restart automatically an animated svg line after finished?

Tags: css, svg

I have an animated svg line using `css`.

I want animation takes 200s as duration, but I want that line restart automatically again after it finish.

This is an example of my code.

```css
line {
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 500%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 \0/;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 \0/;
    -webkit-animation: draw 200s infinite;
    animation: draw 200s infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  0% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  100% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  100% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<svg height="100" width="250">
  <line x1="25" y1="30" x2="45" y2="30" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:4" />
</svg>

</body>
```

In order to restart the animation, I changed `animation` tag:

```
-webkit-animation: draw 200s 2s infinite;
animation: draw 200s 2s infinite;
```

However, the effect I got was:

- first: the line ends after two seconds.
- It starts over with the desired duration (200s). However, after it finish, it doesn't start again immediately.

How can I restart animation automatically after it finish. Do I need to use javascript or jquery?

Comment: can you be more precise ? with your actual code the animation will restart since you specified infinite

Comment: Yeah, but after 200s. I want it sooner. If I reduce the time, the line appears too quickly, that's why I choosed 200s.

Comment: you said :  `I want animation takes 200s as duration, but I want that line restart automatically again after it finish` so can you clarifiy what is the duration you want and when it will restart, etc ?

Comment: The output I got with actual code is: duration: 200s and It restart after 200s. I am looking something different. Duration: 200s. Restart 1s.

Comment: Yes which is logical, as the duration is 200s so when it's done it will restart and this is after the duration of 200s

Comment: if you want it to restart of 1s, means that you want the duration to be 1s ... so adjust the animation values to make it behave like you want for 1s

Comment: As I said, With 1s the line appears too quickly, even with 10s, and 20s. Thats why I choosed 200s.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the duration of your animation is set to 200s, therefore according to your CSS it will loop over again after 200 seconds and a further 2 seconds delay. From what I understand, you want the line to be drawn slowly and therefore you're using a 200s animation, which isn't the best way to achieve that -- at least not since you want the animation to restart after a short delay.

You can make the line slower by using `ease-in` in conjunction with changing the animation as per below. This should achieve the desired affect you're looking for.

```css
line {
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke-dasharray: 500%;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 \0/;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0 \0/;
    -webkit-animation: draw 2s ease-in infinite;
    animation: draw 2s ease-in infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes draw {
  0% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  99% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  100% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes draw {
  0% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  99% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 500%;
  },
  100% {
 stroke-dashoffset: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

<svg height="100" width="250">
  <line x1="25" y1="30" x2="45" y2="30" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:4" />
</svg>

</body>
```